# IE11 - border-radius and box-shadow together cause problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Following my Code:

```css
div{
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
}

div:hover{
    box-shadow: 25px 25px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

It works on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but it does not work well on Internet Explorer 11, there are obvious visual problems when the div is no longer focus. How to solve them?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL0t8g21/

Comment: How are you testing IE11?  IE10, 11 and Edge all look the same to me as Chrome.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle I can see strange artifacts when hovering the div, as Bob describes. Looks to me like a problem with the rendering engine of IE, therefore I believe it is hard to solve. You could try using a JS workaround for the shadow animation, even if this might be a bit too much for a pure IE solution

Comment: Yes, I also tried solving it I agree with @MatthiasS. its a **problem with the rendering engine of IE**, if you want I can create a workaround for you using `:after` or `:before` of you div.

Comment: @weBer ok thank you, it would be very useful...

Comment: @weBer thanks, your solution is not elegant, but it works. If no one finds a better solution I will accept it.

Comment: @Bob I have updated the answer for a better result so please do check it.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to make it little Better.**

As per your request from comment, here is a **workaround** for you using `:after` or `:before` of you div.

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

div:hover:after {
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/539cavfo/)

**This is working fine in IE 11.**